# Write text files without Byte Order Mark (BOM)?

Tags: vb.net, encoding, file-handling, byte-order-mark

I am trying to create a text file using VB.Net with UTF8 encoding, without BOM. Can anybody help me, how to do this?

I can write file with UTF8 encoding but, how to remove Byte Order Mark from it?

edit1:
I have tried code like this;

```
    Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim utf8EmitBOM As New UTF8Encoding(True)
    Dim strW As New StreamWriter("c:\temp\bom\1.html", True, utf8EmitBOM)
    strW.Write(utf8EmitBOM.GetPreamble())
    strW.WriteLine("hi there")
    strW.Close()

        Dim strw2 As New StreamWriter("c:\temp\bom\2.html", True, utf8)
        strw2.Write(utf8.GetPreamble())
        strw2.WriteLine("hi there")
        strw2.Close()
```

1.html get created with UTF8 encoding only and 2.html get created with ANSI encoding format.

Simplified approach - http://whatilearnttuday.blogspot.com/2011/10/write-text-files-without-byte-order.html

Comment: If you don't want a BOM, why are you writing GetPreamble()?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

In order to omit the byte order mark (BOM), your stream must use an instance of [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx) other than [`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) (which is configured to generate a BOM). There are two easy ways to do this:

**1. Explicitly specifying a suitable encoding:**

1. Call the [`UTF8Encoding` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx) with `False` for the `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier` parameter.
2. Pass the `UTF8Encoding` instance to the stream constructor.

```vb
' VB.NET:
Dim utf8WithoutBom As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False)
Using sink As New StreamWriter("Foobar.txt", False, utf8WithoutBom)
    sink.WriteLine("...")
End Using
```

```cs
// C#:
var utf8WithoutBom = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);
using (var sink = new StreamWriter("Foobar.txt", false, utf8WithoutBom))
{
    sink.WriteLine("...");
}
```

**2. Using the default encoding:**

If you do not supply an `Encoding` to `StreamWriter`'s constructor at all, `StreamWriter` will by default use an UTF8 encoding without BOM, so the following should work just as well:

```vb
' VB.NET:
Using sink As New StreamWriter("Foobar.txt")
    sink.WriteLine("...")
End Using
```

```cs
// C#:
using (var sink = new StreamWriter("Foobar.txt"))
{
    sink.WriteLine("...");
}
```

Finally, note that omitting the BOM is only permissible for UTF-8, not for UTF-16.

Comment: Not always wise: for example `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText` writes the BOM if no encoding is specified.

Comment: `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText` is an exception in this regard, guessing for backwards VB compatibility perhaps? [`File.WriteAllText`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,10d1f3f4dbac8234) defaults to UFT8NoBOM.

Comment: This is especially helpful if you want to write a `*.m3u8` playlist file for VLC. VLC is still not capable to read UTF8 playlist files WITH BOM! This seems to be fixed according to https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/21860, but will only be included in VLC v4.

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
Encoding outputEnc = new UTF8Encoding(false); // create encoding with no BOM
TextWriter file = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, outputEnc); // open file with encoding
// write data here
file.Close(); // save and close it
```

Answer (score 6):

Just Simply use the method `WriteAllText` from `System.IO.File`.

Please check the sample from [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This method uses UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM), so
>   using the GetPreamble method will return an empty byte array. If it is
>   necessary to include a UTF-8 identifier, such as a byte order mark, at
>   the beginning of a file, use the WriteAllText(String, String,
>   Encoding) method overload with UTF8 encoding.

Comment: The one from the My namespace does use BOM

Answer (score 5):

If you do not specify an `Encoding` when creating a new [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) the default `Encoding` object used is [`UTF-8 No BOM`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,5516ce201dc06b5f,references) which is created via `new UTF8Encoding(false, true)`.

So to create a text file without the BOM use of of the constructors that do not require you to provide an encoding:

```
new StreamWriter(Stream)
new StreamWriter(String)
new StreamWriter(String, Boolean)
```

Comment: What if I need to specify `leaveOpen`?

Comment: @binki in that case you can not use the default encoding that `StreamWriter` uses.  You'll need to specify `new UTF8Encoding(false, true)` for your encoding to be able to specify `leaveOpen` and not have the BOM.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting note with respect to this: strangely, the static "CreateText()" method of the System.IO.File class creates UTF-8 files **without** BOM.

In general this the source of bugs, but in your case it could have been the simplest workaround :)

Answer (score 3):

I think Roman Nikitin is right. The meaning of the constructor argument is flipped. False means no BOM and true means with BOM.

You get an ANSI encoding because a file without a BOM that does not contain non-ansi characters is exactly the same as an ANSI file. Try some special characters in you "hi there" string and you'll see the ANSI encoding change to without-BOM.

Answer (score 1):

**XML Encoding UTF-8 without BOM**
We need to submit XML data to the EPA and their application that takes our input requires UTF-8 without BOM.  Oh yes, plain UTF-8 should be acceptable for everyone, but not for the EPA.   The answer to doing this is in the above comments.  Thank you **Roman Nikitin**.

Here is a C# snippet of the code for the XML encoding:

```
    Encoding utf8noBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);  
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();  
    settings.Encoding = utf8noBOM;  
        …  
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))  
    {  
        xDoc.WriteTo(xw);  
        xw.Flush();  
    }
```

To see if this actually removes the three leading character from the output file can be misleading.  For example, if you use **Notepad++** (www.notepad-plus-plus.org), it will report “Encode in ANSI”.  I guess most text editors are counting on the BOM characters to tell if it is UTF-8.  The way to clearly see this is with a binary tool like **WinHex** (www.winhex.com).  Since I was looking for a before and after difference I used the Microsoft **WinDiff** application.

Answer (score 0):

For VB.Net visual basic, this is how to make it work:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("FileName", Data, False, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be that your input text contains a byte order mark. In that case, you should remove it before writing.

Comment: Please assist me. How to remove it before writting.

Comment: @user180326 doesn’t the default reader already filter that out for you?

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim sWriter As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(shareworklist & "\" & getfilename() & ".txt", False, Encoding.Default)
```

Gives you results as those you want(I think).

Comment: On my PC it creates ANSI files