# Create Text File Without BOM

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, text-files, byte-order-mark

I tried [this aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437666/write-text-files-without-byte-order-mark-bom) without any success

the code I'm using:

```
// File name
String filename = String.Format("{0:ddMMyyHHmm}", dtFileCreated);
String filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("App_Data"), filename + ".txt");

// Process       
myObject pbs = new myObject();         
pbs.GenerateFile();

// pbs.GeneratedFile is a StringBuilder object

// Save file
Encoding utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(true);
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, utf8WithoutBom);
foreach (string s in pbs.GeneratedFile.ToArray()) 
    tw.WriteLine(s);
tw.Close();

// Push Generated File into Client
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.text";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".txt");
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

the result:

[image]

It's [writing the BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) no matter what, and special chars (like Æ Ø Å) 
are not correct :-/

**I'm stuck!**

My objective is create a file using **UTF-8** as Encoding and **8859-1** as CharSet

Is this so hard to accomplish or I'm just getting a bad day?

*All help is greatly appreciated, thank you!*

Comment: "a file using UTF-8 as Encoding and 8859-1  as CharSet" : encoding and charset are the same thing, so your requirement doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Well it writes the BOM because you are instructing it to, in the line

```
Encoding utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(true);
```

`true` means that the BOM should be emitted, using

```
Encoding utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false);
```

writes no BOM.

> My objective is create a file using UTF-8 as Encoding and 8859-1 as CharSet

Sadly, this is not possible, either you write UTF-8 or not. I.e. as long as the characters you are writing are present in ISO Latin-1 it will look like a ISO 8859-1 file, however as soon as you output a character that is not covered by ISO 8859-1 (e.g. ä,ö, ü) these characters will be written as a multibyte character.

To write true ISO-8859-1 use:

```
Encoding isoLatin1Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

**Edit:** After balexandre's comment

I used the following code for testing ...

```
var filePath = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("dsfaskd jlsadfj laskjdflasjdf asdkfjalksjdf lkjdsfljas dddd jflasjdflkjasdlfkjasldfl asääääjdflkaslj d f");

Encoding isoLatin1Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, isoLatin1Encoding);
tw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
tw.Close();
```

And the file looks perfectly well. Obviously, **you should use the same encoding when reading the file**.

Comment: MSDN says EMIT ... and I kept reading OMIT arghh!!! I tried: Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1") and does not write the BOM, still have trouble regarding special chars though :(

Comment: @balexandre: I read Ømit.  You are forgetting to make the HttpResponse.Charset property match the encoding of the file.  Setting them both to UTF-8 is rather a good idea.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque I downvoted by mistake ... (to much clicks on my hand today! and ... no confirmation message on downvotes) :-/ my mistake though! I quickly upvoted to +1

Comment: @nobugz HttpResponse has nothing to do with the file, the file is already written, HttpResponse is only the sending to the client part

Comment: @balexandre: it does, TransmitFile makes it part of the response.  All text in the response must have the same encoding.

Answer (score -2):

Encoding.UTF8 does not work. Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") works for all type of encodings