# C# StreamWriter writes extra bytes to the Stream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(memStream, Encoding.UTF8, 4194304 /* 4 MiB */, leaveOpen: true))
{
     var str = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', 10240 /* 10 * KiB */).ToArray());
     Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
     Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str).Length);
     sw.Write(str);
     sw.Flush();
     Console.WriteLine(memStream.Length);
}
// Output
// ---------
// 10240
// 10240
// 10243

// Output which I was expecting
// ---------
// 10240
// 10240
// 10240
```

I checked the StreamWriter.Write(String) documentation on MSDN but I didn't find anything which mentions that this API can write extra bytes to the stream.
([MSDN Doc StreamWriter.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=netcore-3.1)).
I am using .NET Core 3.1, but I am guessing this behavior also holds for Core 2.0 and Framework although I have not explicitly tested my hypothesis for them. I read the [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) documentation thoroughly, I don't find any mention of such a behavior. Is this a bug or expected behavior or am I missing something ?

Comment: Although you have included what result you got, you didn't include what you expected to see. Please add.

Comment: I see 10243 as the final line of output - which is what I'd expect from a BOM being added at the start. Do you *repeatedly* get 10305?

Comment: [No repro](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CXiQ6Y)

Comment: I also only see 10243 as the final size.

Comment: I get the same output as @JonSkeet on .NET Core 3.1.0.

Comment: Now I am getting 10243. I think the memory stream which I was using initially had some extra bytes already written. But I understood. The expected output should be 10243 with 10240 for string and 3 bytes for BOM. Thanks :)

Comment: same here; but: if you don't want a BOM, use `new UTF8Encoding(false)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StreamWriter and UTF-8 Byte Order Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266069/streamwriter-and-utf-8-byte-order-marks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run this locally i get

> 10240
>   10240
>   10243

On further inspection the extra 3 bytes appear to be at the beginning of the stream `239 187 191` or `EF BB BF` in hex. This is the Byte Order Mark (BOM) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

To remove these extra characters from the ouptut use `new UTF8Encoding(false)` to omit the BOM, instead of `Encoding.UTF8` in the creation of the StreamWriter

```cs
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(memStream, new UTF8Encoding(false), 4194304 /* 4 MiB */, leaveOpen: true))
```

Comment: Thanks :) . I wasn't aware that StreamWriter adds BOM by default.

Comment: @amit9oct See the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Answer (score 4):

You could prevent the output of the BOM by creating a `UTF8Encoding` that should not emit an UTF8 identifier by using `new UTF8Encoding(false)`:

```
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(memStream, new UTF8Encoding(false), 4194304 /* 4 MiB */, leaveOpen: true))
{
    var str = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', 10240 /* 10 * KiB */).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str).Length);
    sw.Write(str);
    sw.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine(memStream.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) . I wasn't aware that StreamWriter adds BOM by default.