# Why does Notepad++ disable/hide all macros when I programmatically edit shortcuts.xml?

Tags: c#, notepad++, shortcut

If I manually edit `%appdata%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml` and manually add a find replace macro ***(See MACRO below)***, then close shortcuts.xml and then restart Notepad++, the macro is available to run from the Macro Menu button:

[image]

I wrote a program that programmatically edits shortcuts.xml and inserts the very same macro. Notepad++ is not up when I run my program. I know my program is working based on diffing copies of manually modified and programmatically modified shortcuts.xml files. However, when I restart Notepad++ after running my program, the Macro button is "dead", i.e., all macros, although present in shortcuts.xml, disappear from the Macro button.

[image]

Is Notepad++ somehow sensitive to its shortcuts.xml file being programmatically manipulated?

***MACRO Screenshot (text version follows)***

[image: shortcuts.xml]

***Text Version***

```
<Macro name="Redactor" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
  <Action type="0" message="2422" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
  <Action type="0" message="2325" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" />
  <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="IP-Placeholder" />
  <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
  <Action type="0" message="2422" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
  <Action type="0" message="2325" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b" />
  <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="email-placeholder" />
  <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
  <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

Comment: So how are you diffing them -- in particular, do you know for sure your edits aren't messing up the encoding of the file in the process, which your diff tool might paper over?

Comment: Hard to know for sure what is the cause, but if your are curious here is [their github](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus) in case you want to dig into their code or file a bug or [info about their author](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/author/)

Comment: Are you sure the `shortcuts.xml` your program is modifying is the same one that Notepad++ is using? Possible you have two files with the same name in different locations.

Comment: @ibrennan: yes, for sure, same one in %appdata%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml

Comment: @jeroenmostert: I didn't diff them good enough.  When I open the original shortcuts.xml using NotePad++ and click on the encoding menu button, it shows UTF-8. After I run my program, the same file (modified) shows UTF-8 BOM.  So, I'll assume that's the problem and work to make shortcuts.xml stay as UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.

My original (non-working) code did this:

```
// shortcuts.xml is encoded UTF-8, no BOMs
string shortCutsXmlFilepath = Path.Combine($"{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA")}\\NotePad++", "shortcuts.xml");

XDocument shortCutsXmlDocument = XDocument.Load(shortCutsXmlFilepath);

// manipulate xDocument elements .......

shortCutsXmlDocument.Save(shortCutsXmlFilepath);
```

The result was that shortcuts.xml had UTF-8 byte order marks ([BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/byte-order-mark)) inserted (`EF BB BF`) at the beginning of the file. When I next executed Notepad++ and it read shortcuts.xml, it silently failed to read shortcuts.xml and so no macros were displayed under the **Macro** menu button.

**The Fix**

The fix is to read shortcuts.xml using a `StreamReader` and write it using a `StreamWriter`. I explicitly asserted the 'no BOM' option in both so that there's no chance of the saved version of shortcuts.xml having the BOMs inserted (the 'no BOM' option is the default).

[Note: To enable BOM, use new `UTF8Encoding(true)` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266069/streamwriter-and-utf-8-byte-order-marks)

```
XDocument shortCutsXmlDocument = LoadNotepadPpShortcutsXmlDocument();

// manipulate xDocument elements .......

SaveNotepadPpShortcutsXmlDocument(shortCutsXmlDocument);

//
//
//

private static XDocument LoadNotepadPpShortcutsXmlDocument()
{
    string shortCutsXmlFilepath = Path.Combine($"{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA")}\\NotePad++", "shortcuts.xml");

    if (File.Exists(shortCutsXmlFilepath) == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Can't find '{shortCutsXmlFilepath}'");
        Application.Exit();
    }

    XDocument xDocument = new XDocument();

    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path: shortCutsXmlFilepath, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    {
        xDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);
    }

    return (xDocument);
}

private static XDocument SaveNotepadPpShortcutsXmlDocument(XDocument document)
{
    string shortCutsXmlFilepath = Path.Combine($"{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA")}\\NotePad++", "shortcuts.xml");

    //todo Verify that Path.Combine($"{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA")}", "\\NotePad++") exists before writing shortcuts.xml

    using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(shortCutsXmlFilepath, append: false, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    {
        document.Save(stream);
    }

    return (document);
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).