# FileHelpers WriteStream writes no data

Tags: c#, .net, csv, fixed-width, filehelpers

I need to read a fixed width file, map the records to another type and then write that data to a csv stream. I'm trying to use FileHelpers to do so but the `WriteStream` doesn't seem to write any data to the stream.

FixedWidthType.cs (the type to read)

```cs
[FixedLengthRecord, IgnoreFirst(2), IgnoreLast(1)]
public class FixedWidthType
{
    [FieldFixedLength(6), FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string BranchCode { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

CsvType.cs (the type to write)

```cs
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class CsvType
{
    public string BranchCode { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
var readerEngine = new FileHelperEngine<FixedWidthType>();
var writerEngine = new FileHelperEngine<CsvType>();

var file = File.ReadAllBytes("fixedWidthFile.txt");

using (var sr = new MemoryStream(file))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sr))
using (var sw = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(sw))
{
    // read fixedwidth data
    var fixedWidthRecords = readerEngine.ReadStream(reader);

    var csvRecords = fixedWidthRecords.Select(r => new CsvType
    {
        BranchCode = r.BranchCode,
        // ...
    }).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(csvRecords.Count()); // output: 2

    // write csv data
    writerEngine.WriteStream(writer, csvRecords);

    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToArray().Count()); // output: 0

    File.WriteAllBytes("newfile.csv", sw.ToArray());
}
```

The above code writes a blank file. ps: I know I can use `writerEngine.WriteFile` to accomplish the above(which does work btw), but I specifically need a stream in my case. The purpose of writing the file above is only to view the output.

Comment: _"The above code writes a blank file"_ - I think that's because you don't seem to be flushing any of your buffers.

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes("newfile.csv", sw.ToArray());` <-- Using the 100% buffered (i.e. memory inefficient)`File.WriteAll...` methods kinda defeats the point of using Stream-based IO above...

Comment: @Dai, as mentioned at the bottom the last line is just for illustration. My actual use case is writing this data to s3 in a far away piece of code, which will take advantage of the stream.

Comment: So what happens when/if you flush the streams after you write to them?

Comment: Okay you were correct. I had previously tried `sw.Flush()`, but instead I had to `writer.Flush()` after `writerEngine.WriteStream` to write the stream, which makes sense to me now. I am quite new to working with streams in c#. Thank you, you can post this as an answer if you like, any suggestions welcome aswell.

Answer (score 0):

While closing a `TextWriter` and/or its underlying `Stream` (either an via an explicit `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` call - or [implicitly via a `using(){}` block or `using;` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) will also flush it, if you intend to read back from a `Stream` after writing to it *without* closing it, then you'll need to flush the `TextWriter` because it has its own buffer, and you may also need to *rewind* the stream by setting `.Position` too - and take advantage of `leaveOpen: true` too.

```
var readerEngine = new FileHelperEngine<FixedWidthType>();
var writerEngine = new FileHelperEngine<CsvType>();

Byte[] inputBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("fixedWidthFile.txt");

UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true ); // Using the default UTF8Encoding can lead to unexpected proplems: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266069/streamwriter-and-utf-8-byte-order-marks

using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream( inputBytes ))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( inputStream ) )
using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( outputStream, utf8, bufferSize: 4096, leaveOpen: true ) )
{
    var fixedWidthRecords = readerEngine.ReadStream(reader);

    var csvRecords = fixedWidthRecords
        .Select(r => new CsvType
        {
            BranchCode = r.BranchCode,
            // ...
        })
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine( "csvRecords.Count: {0}", csvRecords.Count ); // output: 2

    // write csv data
    writerEngine.WriteStream( writer, csvRecords );

    writer.Flush();
    outputStream.Flush(); // <-- This isn't necessary for a MemoryStream, but will be for a FileStream.

#if OPTION_1

    // Avoid `ToArray()` as that will do an allocation+copy.
    Console.WriteLine( outputStream.Position );
    Console.WriteLine( outputStream.GetBuffer().Length );

    ReadOnlySpan<Byte> msContents = outputStream.GetBuffer().AsSpan( 0, outputStream.Position );

    File.WriteAllBytes( "newfile.csv", msContents );

#elif OPTION_2

    // Close `writer` here (which will also flush it), because we set `leaveOpen: true` the MemoryStream can be reused:
    writer.Dispose();
    // Rewind the MemoryStream:
    outputStream.Position = 0;
    
    using( FileStream fileOutputStream = File.OpenWrite( "newfile.csv" ) )
    {
        await outputStream.CopyToAsync( fileOutputStream );
    }

#endif

}
```

---

*But* if you look at your program's application logic, you don't actually need to `Flush` anything, just change your code to this:

```
var readerEngine = new FileHelperEngine<FixedWidthType>();
var writerEngine = new FileHelperEngine<CsvType>();

UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true ); // Using the default UTF8Encoding can lead to unexpected proplems: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266069/streamwriter-and-utf-8-byte-order-marks

using( FileStream   fixedWidthInputFS     = new FileStream( "fixedWidthFile.txt", FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, FileMode.Open ) )
using( StreamReader fixedWidthInputReader = new StreamReader( fixedWidthInputFS ) )
using( FileStream   outputFS              = new FileStream( "output.dat", FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, FileMode.CreateNew ) )
using( StreamWriter outputWriter          = new StreamWriter( outputFS, utf8 ) ) // <-- Watch out for the default encoding possibly being UTF8 with BOM, 
{
    var csvRecords = readerEngine.ReadStream( fixedWidthInputReader )
        .Select(r => new CsvType
        {
            BranchCode = r.BranchCode,
            // ...
        });

    writerEngine.WriteStream( outputWriter, csvRecords );
}
```

- Protip: When a `Stream` or `TextWriter`/`TextReader` is being used only for input and/or output, you should put the word "input" or "output" (or "in" / "out") in their names to make things easier to follow.