# Removing BOM characters from AJAX-posted string

Tags: c#, .net, byte-order-mark

My content contains multiple BOM (EF BB BF) characters and I want to remove them. The characters are in the middle of strings I want to simply remove them all.

The data containing the BOMS comes from a JavaScript source, which I POST to the backend. For now, they are saved as is, but this results in errors in post-processing when the characters are interpreted and start showing up mid-content. I suspect they come from something that was copypasted into my editor.

I can step through the string char by char, but I don't know how to compare against the BOM. Would it somehow be possible to compare the hex values of the string bytes and compare three byte sequences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The utf-8 BOM bytes get translated to `\ufeff`.  Unicode character "Zero width no-break space", can't see them, can't hear them.  Filter them out with:

```
   var good = bad.Replace("\ufeff", "");
```

Comment: Great success! One question though, might this cause problems by removing other bytes that get translated into the same unicode character? I doubt that I'll miss any if they get removed but are there other important or worth-mentioning such characters?

Comment: You can't see them, you can't hear them.

Comment: To replace any ocurence in the string, use: const goodStr = badStr.split('\ufeff').join('');

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
CleanString = DirtyString.Replace("\u00EF\u00BB\u00BF", null);
```

Comment: The way I tested this was to do `string s2 = s.Replace(...)` and then `Debug.WriteLine(s2);`. Then I copy-pasted the output from my output window to Notepad++ and switched to view HEX: I still see the BOM. Did I try it wrong?

Comment: That's how it is working for me. Maybe you find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502990/create-text-file-without-bom?rq=1) helpful.