# FileSystem.WriteAllText adds non-printable characters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, file-io

Here are two methods for writing text to a file in VB.Net 2012. The first one prepends the same three non-printable characters to each file: ï»¿. The second one works as expected and does not add the three characters. objDataReader is an OleDB datareader.

Any idea why?

Greg

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(lblLocation.Text & "\" & 
objDataReader("MessageControlId").ToString & ".txt", objDataReader("MsgContents").ToString, False)

Using outfile As New StreamWriter(lblLocation.Text & "\" & objDataReader("MessageControlId").ToString & ".txt")
    outfile.Write(objDataReader("MsgContents").ToString)
End Using
```

Comment: It is the BOM, it says that the rest of the file contains utf-8 encoded text.  A BOM is a Good Thing, it is entirely normal and any modern text editor knows how to deal with it.  VS certainly does.  Sadly, StreamWriter uses utf-8 but does not write the BOM by default.  You'll have to add UTF8Encoding as the second argument to the constructor to get it to do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. I found the entry below I after Googled BOM, in case anyone wants a more detailed explanation. While the BOM was not visible in a text editor it did cause problems when I passed the file to our HL7 interface engine.

Greg

[Write text files without Byte Order Mark (BOM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437666/write-text-files-without-byte-order-mark-bom)