# Replace an entire line of text using powershell and regexp?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a programming background, but I am fairly new to both powershell scripting and regexp. Regexp has always eluded me, and my prior projects have never 'forced' me to learn it.

With that in mind I have a file with a line of text that I need to replace. I can not depend on knowing where the line exists, if it has whitespace in front of it, or what the ACTUAL text being replaced IS. I DO KNOW what will preface and preceed the text being replaced.

AGAIN, I will not KNOW the value of "Replace This Text". I will only know what prefaces it "" and what preceeds it "". Edited OP to clarify. Thanks!

**LINE OF TEXT I NEED TO REPLACE**

```html
<find-this-text>Replace This Text</find-this-text>
```

**POTENTIAL CODE**

```powershell
(gc $file) | % { $_ -replace “”, “” } | sc $file
```

- Get the content of the file, enclose this in parentheses to ensure file is first read and then closed so it doesnt throw an error when trying to save the file.
- Iterate through each line, and issue replace statement. **THIS IS WHERE I COULD USE HELP.**
- Save the file by using Set-Content. My understanding is that this method is preferable, because it takes encoding into consideration,like UTF8.

Comment: Do you need this all on one line, or can it be a script?

Comment: @Tony Hinkle - A script will work, might even be preferable!

Comment: Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/string-replace-file-content-with-powershell  This question probably should be closed as a duplicate.  If the answers on that page are what you need, let me know and I'll flag this one for a moderator to remove.

Comment: Do you have an XML file as your `find-this-text` tags suggest, or is the data just plain text and you need to match some known text fragments before and after the text you want replaced? In case of XML you should not use simple string replacements. Also, what exactly do you need replaced? Just the text between the known fragments? Or the entire line? In case of the latter: what is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: It is an XML file, and I have already tried modifying the XML file by casting it as XML and then using the XML cmdlets to navigate and replace the value. The problem I ran into is that by using Xml.Save it changes the encoding type from "UTF-8 without BOM" to "UTF-8". This doesnt seem like a big deal, but it cause the program parsing the xml config file to fail. It is expecting the "UTF without BOM" encoding format. I figured by using a the 'Set-Content' method and parsing it as a regular text file, it would preserve the ORIGINAL encode type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML is not a line oriented format (nodes may span several lines, just as well as a line may contain several nodes), so it shouldn't be edited as if it were. Use a proper XML parser instead.

```
$xmlfile = 'C:\path\to\your.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlfile
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//find-this-text')
$node.'#text' = 'replacement text'
```

For saving the XML in "UTF-8 without BOM" format you can call the [`Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with a [`StreamWriter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437780/1630171) doing The Right Thing™:

```
$UTF8withoutBOM = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($xmlfile, $false, $UTF8withoutBOM)
$xml.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The .* in the regular expression would be considered "greedy" and dangerous by many.  If the line that contains this tag and it's data contains nothing else, then there really isn't any significant risk according to my understanding.

```
$file = "c:\temp\sms.txt"
$OpenTag = "<find-this-text>"
$CloseTag = "</find-this-text>"
$NewText = $OpenTag + "New text" + $CloseTag

(Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$OpenTag.*$CloseTag", $NewText} | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: I apologize. I should have been more specific in my OP, but the portion of text that needs to be replaced could be different. I will not KNOW the value of "Replace This Text". I will only know what prefaces it "<find-this-text>" and what preceeds it "</find-this-text>". Edited OP to clarify. Thanks!