# XmlDocument.Load multiple root elements

Tags: c#, xml

Hello guys I have a problem when I need load a xml

My code is like to

```
Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
xmlDoc.Load(Stream); //--> throw XmlException (multiple root elements in 14,22)
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

The xml file is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dummy="

http://www.somedomian.com/dummybus/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header Id="IDH">
        <dummy:authentication>
            <id>Unique</id>
            <userid>myuser</userid>
        </dummy:authentication>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp>
                <wsu:Created>2015-09-07T12:21:15</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-09-08T12:21:15</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header> <!--- This is line 14 and  > is a column 22--->
    <soapenv:Body>
        <dummy:dummybus>
            <msg>X1</msg>
        </dummy:dummybus>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`<Envelope>` tag is the root of the file, Why send this error and how I can read my file?

**I found something interesting**

When I save the file, instead of keeping it in the Stream, perfectly loaded

```
xmlDoc.Load(urlToFile);
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

it appears that the error only occurs in the Stream, **Why?**

This method convert xml in `String` to a `MemoryStream`

```
public class XmlUtil
    {
        public static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any multiple root elements. Why are you throwing that exception BTW?

Comment: I can't reproduce your exception.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/vgMXob

Comment: Where does that `Stream` come from?  How are you creating it?

Comment: @dbc this is very rare error, I edit the post, it seems that if you load from a String works perfect, as shown in the test

Comment: @jasilva - I read your most recent edit before posting my comment.  That's why I was asking about the provenance of the `Stream`.

Comment: @dbc I posted new, edit before seeing your comment of the stream

Comment: Try using the Utf8 encoding explicitly and disable (or enable) the BOM when writing to your `MemoryStream`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437666/write-text-files-without-byte-order-mark-bom

Comment: My version of `GenerateStreamFromString` does the following: `return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s ?? ""));`

Comment: Still can't reproduce your problem.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/vgMXob (updated).

Comment: @dbc Utf8 in StringWriter generates the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89085/discussion-between-jasilva-and-dbc).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading from a stream, I would assume it's not positioned at the beginning when you call `xmlDoc.Load(Stream)`. What are you doing with the stream before the call?

If your stream supports seeking, you could try moving back to its beginning just before the call:

```
Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
xmlDoc.Load(Stream);
```

Comment: I have exactly this code `Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before Load